# Angular 13 production build time

Tags: angular

I recently upgraded angular 12 to 13. The time of production build in version 12 was about less than one minute, but now it takes more than ten minutes in version 13! Why it takes so long? Or I've done wrong in doing something?
I use this cli command for production build:

> ng build --configuration production

Comment: Is ngcc still running for any libraries that don't yet support an Ivy distribution?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't updated to `v13` yet but try running `npm ci`. Maybe something went wrong in the update process of angular.